# How to refresh a model with a time limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

Hi all thanks for helping me out with my issue

Ruby version :2.6.5

Rails version :Rails 6.0.2.1

Database : oracle

I am current fetching my data and being outputted in a chart form 
in my view hence how do I update my chart in an hourly manner instead of constantly updating it by fetching the  data from the database

Comment: How are you doing it now, how do you want to see it? Please add details

Comment: I am using the gem chart kick to output a chart in my view template as I have a user model that contains all the users and its role in my view I just output the code <%= pie_chart User.group(:role).count %> in my view template basically I just want to automatically refresh the view page to update all the records hourly

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question. Add your code as a [mcve]. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might want to try is caching technique called Low-Level Caching https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  def chart_data
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key_with_version}/chart_data", expires_in: 1.hours) do
      find_chart_data(id)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks bud i will look into it